# How to auto correct date format in textfield when manually entered by user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, the date format is MM/DD/YYYY. If the user types 13/32/2023 then it should autocorrect 13(the month field) to 12(or 03) as month cannot be more than 12. Same with dates as some months are only till 30th and the other till 31st.

Code: - It is a Textfield from Material UI

```
  <Textfield
           {...params}
           value={value}
           InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
           placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
           sx={calender}
   />
```

Comment: What's wrong with reporting the error to the user and let them re-enter an invalid date?

Comment: This is what the designers want

Comment: I think it could be easy if you use **Calendar** not a **Textfield**. Or make an validator.

Comment: I have used a date picker but it also has a renderInput prop to write date manually. That is where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Datepicker instead manually setting the Textfield and its format.
Simple Datepicker will work for you

```
<DemoContainer components={['DatePicker']}>
   <DatePicker label="Basic date picker" />
</DemoContainer>
```

Check below codesandbox demo for more clarity,

https://codesandbox.io/s/se2son?file=/demo.js